# Re use jwt to call API from another API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth, oauth-2.0, owin, azure-active-directory

I have a single tenant scenario in Azure Active Directory where an API1 needs to call another API2 using authentication, and where the API1 was called from a SPA.

Would it be correct to just pass on the user's JWT received in API1 from the SPA to call API2 for authentication?

[image]

```
new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters() {
            SaveSigninToken = true,
            ...
```

like in: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof

All APIs are implemented with ASP.NET Web API and the SPA using Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) for JavaScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Passing the token you got from the first step would NOT be correct for the second step. Every access token has a specific audience that the token is intended for, and because API 1 and API 2 are different, the audience value of that token can only match one of the two.

You link to the correct sample, which is the On-Behalf-Of flow. This flow allows API 1 to exchange the first token for a brand new token where the client becomes API 1 and the resource becomes API 2.

You can find a description of the protocol [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-on-behalf-of)

```
// line breaks for legibility only

POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer
&client_id=625391af-c675-43e5-8e44-edd3e30ceb15
&client_secret=0Y1W%2BY3yYb3d9N8vSjvm8WrGzVZaAaHbHHcGbcgG%2BoI%3D
&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.windows.net
&assertion=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6InowMzl6ZHNGdWl6cEJmQlZLMVRuMjVRSFlPMCIsImtpZCI6InowMzl6ZHNGdWl6cEJmQlZLMVRuMjVRSFlPMCJ9.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.R-Ke-XO7lK0r5uLwxB8g5CrcPAwRln5SccJCfEjU6IUqpqcjWcDzeDdNOySiVPDU_ZU5knJmzRCF8fcjFtPsaA4R7vdIEbDuOur15FXSvE8FvVSjP_49OH6hBYqoSUAslN3FMfbO6Z8YfCIY4tSOB2I6ahQ_x4ZWFWglC3w5mK-_4iX81bqi95eV4RUKefUuHhQDXtWhrSgIEC0YiluMvA4TnaJdLq_tWXIc4_Tq_KfpkvI004ONKgU7EAMEr1wZ4aDcJV2yf22gQ1sCSig6EGSTmmzDuEPsYiyd4NhidRZJP4HiiQh-hePBQsgcSgYGvz9wC6n57ufYKh2wm_Ti3Q
&requested_token_use=on_behalf_of
&scope=openid
```

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer, but I still have a doubt. This would be despite that API2 is on the same Azure tenant (would be an internal call) and I could "potentially" use the same Audience/ClientId in API2 as in API1? 
It looks like it's a "conceptual" limitation only? Why can't I do it? Could you state/refer me to the protocol concept I'm missing?

Comment: If API 1 and API 2 use the same client ID and app ID uri (resource identifier), then absolutely they can share the same access token... My question at that point is does that really represent two different services? Your picture implies two unique applications but if they share the same app registration then there is no  difference in the eyes of authentication and authorization

Comment: I want to add that ultimately, OAuth 2 is used to protect the resource from giving out data to the wrong clients. End of the day, API 2 could give access to any client that passes a random string as an access token. And in that regard, you could program your api to accept tokens with the wrong resource in the audience claim... Those choices are on you, but that would be a divergence from what OAuth 2 specifies

Comment: Ok. In my case both APIs are hosted in different App Services but on the same Tenant. 
Really not sure if it would "make sense" to register another "Azure AD App" for the API 1 for example, in order to do the "on-behalf-of" flow.

Comment: I would say that apps registered in the same tenant really mean nothing in terms of authorization between the two applications. So ignore those aspects from your decision. If the applications are logically and physically different identities, then you should register separate applications for each. Otherwise, it is up to you. Other common problems you may run into if you do not separate the application identities: App Name, App Branding, App Roles/Assignments, Life-cycle Management, etc...

Comment: Thanks for your help! Yes, that makes sense.